# WCF Service Client with .NET 4.5 Task-Based Async Operations, await never returns

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, async-await

I've added a WCF service reference to my .NET 4.5 app, using the default "Generate task-based operations" option under "Allow Generation of asynchronous operations." I'm calling the service from an async method of my own, sort of like so:

```
public async Task<SomeData> GetDataAsync()
{
    var client = new MyServiceClient();
    var result = await client.GetSomeDataAsync();

    return result;
}
```

The `await client.GetSomeDataAsync()` never completes (a breakpoint on the return statement never gets hit) and I don't get a time out or any other error, no exception is thrown, nothing. Fiddler shows that the client sent the request and the service responded almost instantly with the expected data, so the problem is on my side of the fence somehow.

If I switch to the synchronous version instead

```
var result = client.GetSomeData();
```

The call returns as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know your await statement is never completing?  In your example you are just returning the result.  You can try putting a statement after the await statement to try accessing the result.Result property to see if there is anything there.

Comment: The return statement never gets executed. I set a breakpoint and tried to step through the await, it never continued.

Comment: Your calling code is just starting the task, you haven't shown how you're observing its results.  That's important.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My [chest hairs are tingling](http://movie-lines.tumblr.com/post/618304653/my-chest-hairs-are-tingling-somethings-wrong), Mr. T. I strongly suspect that further up your (client-side) call stack, you have some code that is calling `Task<T>.Result` or `Task.Wait`, which [significantly increases the possibility of a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (as I explain on my blog).

By default, when you `await` a `Task`, the `await` will capture a "context" and use that to resume the `async` method. If this is a context like a UI thread context, and then the code *blocks* the UI thread (i.e., calling `Result` or `Wait`), then the `async` method cannot resume on that UI thread.

I [pity the fool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJnKm6ftPu0) who would attempt to mix synchronous and asynchronous code. Just use [`async` all the way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (as I describe in an MSDN article).

Comment: Almost had to downvote you for all the Mr. T references.  ;-)

Comment: Your Spidey Sense is dead on! In my "upstream" code, I most certainly am doing a `GetDataAsync().Result` - the method where I'm calling `.Result` is a non-async override of a base class method and I wasn't sure how to get around that limitation. I'll check the links in your answer and get this done the right way...

Comment: And yes, I totally missed the Mr. T references... ;-)

Comment: The non-async override of a base class method *is* a problem. If possible, I'd say to make the base class method return a `Task`; synchronous implementations can return `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: In this case, I can't change the base class implementation (it's a .NET class -- AuthorizeAttribute in this case). 

My solution (which seems to be working) is to do something like `var myData = Task.Run(() => myLibraryObject.GetDataAsync()).Result;` -- I've also added `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to the WCF service async method call inside of `GetDataAsync()`

Comment: @Mr.T: Since you're on ASP.NET, I recommend you use the synchronous service call instead of `Task.Run`. Also, [please vote](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1185).